# postcss not recognized as cmdlet

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm, postcss, powershell-cmdlet

anyone got the idea why my postcss is not recognized when installed locally with npm? I've tried with postcss in dependecies, and devDependency aswell. its so frustrating. Tried to run it also from `./node_modules` and `./node_modules/postcss-cli`

i DID install postcss and postcss-cli. When installed globally, everything works, but i need to have it installed locally.

[image]

Comment: is it in your PATH?

Comment: @Metzli_Tonaltzintli no its not, but should it be added automatically? i mean it works when its globally installed but i dont know if it should be in the PATHS when its only local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLIs that come with `npm` packages that are installed *project-locally*  are *not* added to the `PATH` environment variable, so they cannot be invoked by *name only*.

However, `npm` provides helper utility `npx` for invoking such project-local CLIs:

```
npx postcss
```

Note that, by contrast, command lines specified for use with `npm run` inside  `package.json` files *implicitly* know about project-local CLIs, so that use of `npx` isn't necessary there.